# PHP ssh - команда не выполняется No such file or directory на удаленном хосте

Tags: php, linux, ssh

Использую Phpseclib, стандартные команды работают нормально.
Пытаюсь выполнить c удаленного хоста команду на другом хосте.

```
$ssh = new SSH2($host);
if (!$ssh->login($ssh_name, $ssh_pass)) {
    exit('Не могу авторизоваться по SSH!<br>');
}

$command_ssh_list = '/usr/bin/curl --disable-eprt -P - -sk "'.$ftp_type.'://'.$req_host.$req_path.'" --user "'.$req_user.':'.$req_pass.'" --connect-timeout 30 | /usr/bin/wc -l';

$list_file = $ssh->exec('"'.$command_ssh_list.'"');
```

Выдает ошибку: string(177) "bash: /usr/bin/curl --disable-eprt -P - -sk sftp://10.0.00.00:22/aкс/inc/rtc/ --user user:pass --connect-timeout 30 | /usr/bin/wc -l: No such file or directory "

Если выполнить команду напрямую на хосте - выполняется без ошибок
Вот так :

```
/usr/bin/curl --disable-eprt -P - -sk sftp://10.0.00.00:22/aкс/inc/rtc/ --user user:pass --connect-timeout 30 | /usr/bin/wc -l
```

Не могу понять какой файл или директорию он не видит при выполнении через phpseclib

Comment: А зачем вы команду в кавычки дополнительно завернули?

Comment: Phpseclib они нужны доя него

Comment: Не знаю что это, но кавычки не нужны.

Comment: Ниже посмотрите на рабочий вариант. Проблема не с кавычками,  с ними работает и в баш напрямую.

Comment: В варианте ниже нет лишних кавычек.

Comment: Возможно мой косяк. Правда не понятно тогда как оно с кавычками работало ранее.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял почему так заработало, но если формировать команду в переменной непосредственно перед соединением по ssh, то работает без ошибок

```
$command_ssh_list = '/bin/bash -c \'curl --disable-eprt -P - -sk \''.$ftp_type.'://'.$req_host.$req_path.'\' --user \''.$req_user.':'.$req_pass.'\' --connect-timeout 10\' | wc -l';
$list_file = $ssh->exec($command_ssh_list);
```